Calcular la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento SQL
¿Existe manera de calcular la edad a partir de la fecha de nacimiento en la misma? Linea sql (dividir el año de la fecha y hacer la diferencia con la fecha actual)
El campo en la tabla se llama fecha_nacimiento y viene en formato YYYY-MM-DD. He leido un poco y veo que usando GETDATE(), pero no se como adicionarlo a la línea. La idea es mostrar la edad de las personas en la consulta.
$qry=mysql_query("SELECT nombre, identificacion, cargo, 
    concat(direccion) AS direccion, 
    concat(barr,' ',barrio,' ',municipio_vive) AS zona, 
    municipio, estadotrabajador, YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) AS year 
    FROM datos_archivo 
    $mos $m 
    ORDER BY nombre ASC"
);

Lo sé hacer con funciones en PHP, pero directo de la consulta SQL ¿se puede?

Puedes usar DATEDIFF para comparar la fecha actual vs la fecha de nacimiento
 select DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), fecha_nacimiento)

Pero eso te dará la diferencia en días. Si lo divides por 365 te dará la diferencia en años:
 select DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), fecha_nacimiento)/365

Pero eso te dará años con decimales. Si quieres un número cerrado, puedes usar FLOOR
 select FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), fecha_nacimiento)/365)


Se te olvida que existen los años bisiestos.

Bueno, si alguien nació el 29 de febrero hay que dividir la edad por 4. :)

Utiliza la función timestampdiff que te devuelve la diferencia entre dos fechas en el período que quieras, por ejemplo, años. Utiliza la función CURDATE para obtener la fecha actual y así obtener la edad actual:
Por ejemplo:
SELECT   nombre
       , fecha_nacimiento
       , YEAR(fecha_nacimiento) AS anio_nacimiento
       , TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, fecha_nacimiento, CURDATE()) edad
  FROM datos_archivo

fiddle
